# Where can I find a list of Canadian Ports of Entry (POE) and their operating hours?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada

The title pretty much says it all.  I've been searching for a list of Canadian POEs but have so far come up empty-handed.  I'm hoping to apply for a NAFTA work visa (which can be applied for at a POE) and I'm trying to figure out the most convenient location and time to cross the border.  Specifically, I'm curious if international airports are considered POEs and if they only open for business during certain hours of the day.

Comment: If you're looking to enter by land, I suspect that every major road crossing the border will meet your needs.  I don't know about where to check the operating hours, though I am fairly certain that if I were you I wouldn't want to be applying for entry in the middle of the night.

Comment: I applied for my first TN going in the other direction at the Thousand Islands bridge at 3:30 am. I was trying to get to Elmsford, NY by 9:00 for my first day of work.

Comment: @Dennis did the hour affect the process?  Were the officers suffering from sleep deprivation?  Did it go really quickly and smoothly because they didn't have much else to do?

Comment: @phoog, It was quick and easy, though I only saw one guy there so I might have had to wait a while if there'd been someone else to deal with. He also didn't want to do the import paperwork for the car for a reason that sounded like an excuse to make me leave sooner than later, but that suited me anyway so I didn't insist. I was still late for work (so much for first impressions) but only a little.

Answer (score 2):

Canada Border Services Agency has a list of [Airport of Entry (AOE)](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/do-rb/services/aoe-eng.html) locations which include operating hours.

For an airport, anytime a commercial passenger flight might land, there will be CBSA agents available to process arriving passengers. It's probably a good idea to call them before you arrive to confirm that they can handle your application at the time and place you intend to arrive.

There are also [other services offered by CBSA](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/do-rb/services/menu-eng.html) which include arrivals by other means of transportation (eg. by ferry, seaplane, road, rail, etc).

Comment: Not important, but you might want to edit CSBA to CBSA. CSBA is for Canadian School Boards association.

Comment: I contacted one of the AOE's on that list (Charlottetown, PEI) about applying for a work visa the airport, and this was their response: "We are indeed an Airport of Entry, so I asked the local CBSA office about
your enquiry. They tell me that you can either apply at the Canadian Consulate or at the land border and that they do not have the paperwork here to apply."  So apparently not all AOE's provide immigration services?

Comment: @NathanFriend I suspect you would get a different answer with a larger airport. I don't know for sure though.

Comment: @GregHewgill - Thanks for the response.  I agree, but that's my point.  How can I be sure that the POE provides the services I need?  That's the list I'm interested in.

Comment: Charlottetown is an "AOE/60", which means it has restrictions on the types of passengers it can process (I don't know where the definitions of the codes can be found). This time of year I think the CBSA there will only have private flights to deal with. Picking an airport that calls itself an unqualified "AOE" should give you a different result.

Comment: P.S. the "60" is the number of passengers on the plane, but also implies limits on the work they'll do.